# Unable to match string in a if loop in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to check for a sentence in a file. I have this so far, but it always prints "one". Expected is "zero". Is there a problem with my regex?

File contents:

```
This is the header.
  Test is a pass.
This is the footer.
```

Code is below:

```
set file [open "test.report" r]

while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
   if {[regexp {\s+Test is a pass} $line]} {
      puts "zero"
   } else {
      puts "one"
   }
}

close $file
```

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the RE or the rest of your sample code (which should print something like `zero`,`one`,`zero` on that exact input) but when searching for a phrase you perhaps ought to use whole-file searching rather than line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks, how can I do the search by reading the whole-file in one shot?

Comment: `set fileContents [read $file]` then you perform the regexp on this variable. Do note that a larger file will take more time. Otherwise, you can still check line by line if you change the code a bit, so that it still prints either zero or one; you can use a variable that is equal to zero before the loop, set it to one if you find the text and exit the loop, then print this variable after the loop. Also, check your condition, you have it currently print zero if the text is matched right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if a string is present, and you're not searching through too large a file (100MB isn't “too large” in this context, but 1GB is getting close) then you can just load the file in at once and use a line-aware regexp-matching mode.

```
set f [open "thefile.report"]
set data [read $f]
close $f

if {[regexp -line {\s+Test is a pass} $data]} {
    puts "The test passed"
} else {
    puts "The test did not pass"
}
```

You'll still need to think carefully about what to actually search for. In particular, if the file contains ANSI colour codes then your test needs to match them too.

---

For large files, processing a line at a time is right, but then you need to get the semantics right. It's easiest to write a helper procedure for this, and `try`…`finally`… helps a lot too:

```
proc isMatching {filename regular_expression} {
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
            if {[regexp -- $regular_expression $line]} {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}

if {[isMatching "thefile.report" {\s+Test is a pass}]} {
    puts "The test passed"
} else {
    puts "The test did not pass"
}
```

If you have files with single lines over 1GB long, then you've got something *truly horrible.* It's possible to build processing systems to cope with this, but it's nasty and requires trickier techniques. Ask again if you're unlucky enough to be stuck with this…

Comment: Thanks for your help, will certainly check it out.